# Can not print last line of the file

Tags: c

this is my code. It's a school project, we are not allowed to use fopen, just to let you know. I want to read the text file into a string, but the last line is not read. I think I know why, as I state, that whenever c == '\n' it prints a new line, but the last line has '\0' at the end. I just don't know how to fix it really.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct contact
{
    char name[100];
    int number[100];
};

void read_lines()
{
    char line[100];
    char c;
    int i = 0;

    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if ( c == '\n')
        {   
            printf("%s", line);
            for (int j = 0; line[j] != '\0'; j++)
            {
                line[j] = '\0';     
            }
            i = 0;               
        }
        line[i] = c;
        i++;
    }    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    read_lines();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the text file:

```
Mark Brown
6846516516
Jane Black
6848489468
John White
8526848654
```

Comment: What are the contents of `line[]` when the `while()` loop terminates?

Comment: Does the last line end in a newline?

Comment: Are you just saying that the output produced by your program does not have a final newline?  That's because you aren't writing the `\n` for the current line until the next line is written.  Instead of putting the newlines at the beginning of the line, put them at the end.

Comment: getchar returns an int not a char - see https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar

Comment: @Fe2O3 Contents of line are everything except for the last line of the text file.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, when c == to new line character it prints that line, but because the last has a \0 at the end, it does not print it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I don't know if I understand correctly. There is a new line character at the end of every line, except for the last line. There is \0.  So you would change condition or what exactly?

Comment: So... Add another print statement AFTER THE LOOP  to "flush" the final buffer load...

Comment: I am confused, your comment addressed at me seems to show that you understand that your code only prints lines which end in newlines. The last line does not have one. It is not printed. So what is still unclear?

Comment: @Fe2O3 It does actually print everything if I put another print right after the while loop. But after the while loop it only prints the last line. The rest is in the first print in if condition

Comment: Reproducing is kind of tricky, because of the special input needed. Please try `if ( c == '\n')` -> `if ( (c == '\n')||(c=='\0'))`.

Comment: @Yunnosch Well I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @Yunnosch I will try that right away

Comment: "The rest is in the first print in if condition"... It had better be, because once a line has been printed you've written code to zero-out the buffer before the next line is read-in... If you have 6 lines of input and get 6 lines of output... Aren't we done here???

Comment: @Yunnosch If I edit the condition the output is the same, everything apart from the last line.

Comment: Try `int c;   do 
    {
        c = getchar();
        if ((c == '\n')||(c==EOF))` and later `}   while ( c != EOF) ;`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an `int` variable to be able to meaningfully compare to `EOF`.
Also, you need to trigger the output for the last line, which does not have a trailing newline, on which your code currently triggers only.

To fix that make sure that the output can also be triggered by the `EOF`.
I.e. use the post-checking `do-while` and change the condition to also output on the `EOF` which is then available in the last iteration of the loop.

```
void read_lines()
{
    char line[100];
    int c;
    int i = 0;

    do 
    {
        c = getchar();
        if ((c == '\n')||(c==EOF))
        {   
            printf("%s", line);
            for (int j = 0; line[j] != '\0'; j++)
            {
                line[j] = '\0';     
            }
            i = 0;               
        }
        line[i] = c;
        i++;
    }   while ( c != EOF) ;
}
```

Output in what I hope is a correct reproduction of your problem:

```
Mark Brown
6846516516
Jane Black
6848489468
John White
8526848654
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your issue is not about reading the last line, but that the output of your program does not contain the final newline.  If that interpretation is correct, it is easily fixed.  Just write the newlines at the end of each line instead of at the start of the next.  For instance:

```
int c;
char line[100];

while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && i < sizeof line - 1 ){
    line[i++] = c;
    if( c == '\n' ){ 
        line[i] = '\0'; 
        fputs(line, stdout);
        i = 0;               
    }
}
```

Note that this still does not handle long lines very well, but fixes the stated concern (if I interpret the stated concern correctly!).

Note also that I've changed the type of `c`.  The value returned by `getchar` is an `int`, and you must not assign it to a `char` if you want to accurately distinguish EOF from valid data in the file.

Also note the bounds check on `i`.  Lines in a text file can easily exceed 100 characters, and your program should not misbehave when that happens. (Although one could argue that simply terminating the loop on a long line is "misbehaving", it's not quite so bad as overflowing the bounds of the array.)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer! Secondly, it's stated in our project assignment that a line will not exceed over 100 characters. Unfortunately, your solution doesn't; work for me, it just doesn't print anything at all.

Answer (score -2):

`getchar` will not be useful for your project as it reads from the standard input `stdin`.

You should have a look at the `read` function.

Comment: `getchar` is perfectly usable.  The program is supposed to read from stdin.  (Indeed, all programs that read data should read from stdin, as it is the standard place to get input!)

Comment: I have to read from stdin. It is part of the project. Read function is not available.